# Linq result data binding - How to change the column header?

Tags: c#, linq

Linq result data binding- How to change the column header?. Grid enabled with pagination and sorting. I am trying to change the column names with spaces for e.g. Companyname = Company Name. How to so this?

```
var finalResult = AllCompany.Select(i => new
{
    noteLink = i.ID.ToString(),                         //1
    editLink = i.ID.ToString(),                         //2
    CompanyName = i.Fields["Company Name"].ToString(),  //3
    Address1 = i.Fields["Address Line 1"].ToString(),   //4
})
.Distinct()
.OrderByDescending(i => i.CompanyName)
.ToArray();

GvResults.DataSource = finalResult.ToList();
GvResults.DataBind();
```

Comment: `Web` or `Windows` Gridview?

Answer (score 1):

To do that, you might want to declare a POCO:

```
public class CompanySearchResult {
    [Browsable(false)]
    public string noteLink {get;set;}
    [Browsable(false)]
    public string editLink {get;set;}
    [DisplayName("Company Name")]
    public string CompanyName {get;set;}
    [DisplayName("Address Line 1")]
    public string Address1 {get;set;}
}
```

and do:

```
var finalResult = AllCompany.Select(i => new CompanySearchResult
{
    noteLink = i.ID.ToString(),                         //1
    editLink = i.ID.ToString(),                         //2
    CompanyName = i.Fields["Company Name"].ToString(),  //3
    Address1 = i.Fields["Address Line 1"].ToString(),   //4
})
// etc
```